# MongoDB big data processing takes huge amount of time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I had ran into a pretty big issue in my project where I use MongoDB as the database. I have a growing collection, with 6 million documents on which I would like to find duplicates in the past 90 days. The issue is that the optimal, logical solution that I came up with doesn't work because of a bottleneck, and everything that I had tried after that is suboptimal.

**The documents:** Each document contains 26 fields, but the relevant ones are `created_at`, and `fingerprint`. The first one is obvious, the second one is a field composed of some multiple fields - in function of this one I detect duplicate documents.

**The problem:** I made a function that needs to remove duplicate documents in the past 90 days.

**Solutions that I've tried:**

1. The aggregation pipeline: first `$search` using range, with `gt`: today - 90 days; second step I `$project` the document's `_id`, `fingerprint`, and `posted_at` fields, third step I `$group` by `fingerprint`, count it, and push into an array the items, last step `$match` the documents that have a count more than 1.

Here I found out that the `$group` phase is really slow, and I've read that the it can be improved, by sorting by the grouped field before. But the problem is that sorting after the search phase is a bottleneck, but if I remove the search phase I get even more data, which makes the calculations even worse. Also, I have noticed that not pushing the items in the group phase significantly improves the performance, but I need that.

If someone had this problem before, or knows the solution to it, please advise me on how to handle it.

I'm using the MongoDB C# driver, but that shouldn't matter, I believe.

Comment: If you had a native index on `{ created_at: 1, fingerprint: 1, _id: 1 }` then you could do a covered query (avoid fetching the full document) as well as avoid some overhead of going back and forth with Atlas Search. Of course if you don't already have that index then creating it requires a full collection scan.  In the future perhaps consider creating a `unique` index on `fingerprint` to avoid duplicates from being created?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response! I can't really create a unique index on it, because I allow duplicate fingerprints, if the latest entry with that fingerprint is more than 90 days in the past. I will try the covered query, and get back as soon as I have a definite response whether it worked.

Comment: Do you really use `$search`? This is a full text search and certainly not suitable for date filters.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, the aggregation pipeline you did and desired result. I have some ideas but without any data it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you should know that group is not very fast but index can help it by using COUNT_SCAN search.

I think you need to create a compound index for the `created_at` and `fingerprint`

```js
schema.index({created_at: 1, fingerprint: 1});
```

then you need to sort your aggregate pipeline to be like this

```js
const time = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { created_at: {$gt: time}},  // the index will be used
  { $group: { _id: "$fingerprint", count: {$sum: 1}}},  // the index will be used
  { $match: {count: {$gt: 1}},
])
```

After getting the names that have duplicate fingerprint value you can make requests to delete duplicate and only keep one because $push in group will slow down the group step.

`Note:` the code here is in JS language.

Comment: Thank you. But wouldn't this imply, that for example if I have 50k duplicate fingerprints, I would need to make 50k calls to fetch items with the fingerprints that I get from the aggregation?

Comment: nope you need only 2 calls
one to get all the recods ids for all duplicate fingerprints.
then keep only one id per every fingerprint value.
then make a second call to delete all duplicates.